# Cannot debug with PhpStorm + Vagrant + XDebug

Tags: xdebug, phpstorm, vagrant

I cannot get XDebug to work with PhpStorm and Vagrant on a Windows 7 machine. I've already followed every tutorial on getting this to work but with no luck.

So what I've tried is:

- PhpStorm always listens to debug connections
- xdebug.ini file with the following:

```
zend_extension = "..../xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable= 1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host= 33.33.33.10
xdebug.remote_port= 9000
xdebug.remote_connect_back= 1
xdebug.remote_autostart= 1
xdebug.remote_log = "...."
```

- Setup PhpStorm to connect to `localhost:8080` and too `33.33.33.10`, both with no luck.
- The log file always outputs:

```
I: Checking remote connect back address.
W: Remote address not found, connecting to configured address/port: 33.33.33.10:9000. :-|
E: Could not connect to client. :-(
```

- The firewall (ESET Smart Security) is always turned-off when I try to debug
- Set path mappings, didn't work either

I just don't know what to do, but I really NEED to be able to debug.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: What machine 33.33.33.10 belongs to -- your real one (where PhpStorm tuns) or virtual (Vagrant)?  It has to be the IP of machine with PhpStorm (as seen from virtual machine) -- check what `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` has. Good article to read: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Zero-configuration+Web+Application+Debugging+with+Xdebug+and+PhpStorm

Comment: 33.33.33.10 belongs to Vagrant, but on Windows everyone says it has to be the VM and not the machine with PhpStorm

Comment: It has to be IP of an computer where debug client (PhpStorm in our case) is running -- check what xdebug manual says about xdebug.remote_host. **UNLESS** you are using SSH tuneling and/or xdebug proxy (which is a bit strange (mainly proxy) since it's on the same computer and not somewhere on internet behind firewalls and routers) -- in this case listen what "everyone says" and ask them how to set it up -- I have not worked with this.

Comment: If it still does not work: **1)** make sure that it's actually PhpStorm who listens on xdebug port and not another program ([tcpview](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx) or standard `netstat` can show such info; **2)** See if you can connect from your vagrant box to PhpStorm on that port using `telnet` (in case connection issues: firewall or whatever.

Comment: Ok: PhpStorm is listening on port 9000, VBoxHeadless is also listening on port 9000, but nothing than that

Comment: I may only suggest checking these 2 links (in case you have not seen them yet) -- it's enough to make it work when PHP/Apache is running on virtual server (or on LAN): **1)** http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Xdebug+Installation+Guide **2)** http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Zero-configuration+Web+Application+Debugging+with+Xdebug+and+PhpStorm

Comment: @LazyOne, thanks for you help - actually the problem was very stupid- I forwarded port 9000 in the Vagrantfile which I didn't have to...

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The problem was very stupid - I forwarded port 9000 in the Vagrantfile, and I didn't have to do so...

Now, actually I see that the only necessary lines in xdebug.ini are:

```
zend_extension = ...
xdebug.remote_enable = on
xdebug.remote_connect_back = on
```

The setup is pretty straightforward, if you don't do stupid things...

Comment: For those wondering why it started working for Nadav when he stopped forwarding port 9000, it's because Xdebug actually works the other way around. Instead of your computer connecting to your Vagrant box on port 9000, Xdebug actually works in reverse—your Vagrant box will connect to your Xdebug client on your (host) computer. James Walker has a nice explanation of that [here](http://walkah.net/blog/debugging-php-with-vagrant/).

Comment: Even the remote_handler is not needed - dbgp is set by default.

Comment: The `debug.remote_connect_back = on` is exactly what I needed: Mac OS X host, running vagrant with Ubuntu 14.04 on.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you connect to the right url from within PHPStorm. My vagrant box has the ip of 192.168.50.2 for instance, so i have to set the url of my project => 192.168.50.2

Comment: Thanks 30equals, I have managed to solve the issue now. The only problem was that I've forwarded port 9000 in the Vagrantfile which I didn't have to... Regarding your answer - I already tried that but thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I had to set

```
xdebug.remote_connect_back = '0'
xdebug.remote_host= '10.0.2.2'
```

so my whole config looks like this:

```
xdebug.default_enable: '1'
xdebug.remote_autostart: '1'
xdebug.remote_connect_back: '0'
xdebug.remote_enable: '1'
xdebug.remote_handler: dbgp
xdebug.remote_host: '10.0.2.2'
xdebug.max_nesting_level: '400'
```

Host: Linux

VM: Vagrant with PuPHPet using VirtualBox

nothing special to configure in PhpStorm

found it here: http://jeromejaglale.com/doc/php/xdebug_vagrant_puphpet_phpstorm