# PhpStorm and XDebug on Vagrant Homestead

Tags: php, vagrant, phpstorm, xdebug, homestead

I'm on Windows and I'm trying to debug a Web application (hosted with Vagrant/Homestead) using PhpStorm through XDebug. I tried many configurations but I can't get things working. The PhpStorm XDebug setup is pretty common.

This is the current xdebug configuration:

vagrant@homestead: **/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini**

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable = on
xdebug.remote_connect_back = on
xdebug.idekey='PHPSTORM'
```

In the IDE "Start listening for PHP debug connections" it's turned on. When I attempt to start debugging a new chrome tab opens and the URL ends, for example, with `?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=16588` but the debugger doesn't run and this is what the IDE says:

[image]

Also, **netstat** says the port 9000 is still listening.
Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are changing the 20-xdebug.ini file for the Command Line Interface (CLI). Instead you need to change the `/etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini` for the Apache settings, since you are using Chrome.

**UPDATE**

I'm not sure of the differences between Apache and Nginx (which may be  `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini`), but here is how I got it working with a VirtualBox VM running Apache, on a Windows computer.

Settings for 20-xdebug.ini:

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=192.168.1... (your windows IP address within your network)
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.autostart=1
```

Comment: Katie thank you for your answer. I followed many guides and none mentioned apache. I guess vagrant homestead runs nginx and and not apache. Also, phpinfo() seems reporting the right values. I guess it's a problem between phpstorm and the vagrant virtual machine communication but I dont really understand what's wrong..

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15339165/cannot-debug-with-phpstorm-vagrant-xdebug?rq=1

Comment: I feel so dumb asking this but...XDebug has to be configured on my windows environment or in the vagrant machine environment?

Comment: No question is dumb, on your vagrant box, you refer to your Windows machine IP address so it can make the connection back to it.

Comment: Ok I managed to get it working. The problem was that PHPStorm located the wrong php executable in /usr/bin/. I changed it manually from /usr/bin/php to /usr/bin/php7.0 then I configured the 20-xdebug.ini in the FPM folder and it's done. Thank you very much for your help Katie, I really appreciated it.

Comment: *"The problem was that PHPStorm located the wrong php executable in /usr/bin/."* That's not how it works. 1) It's you who tell what correct PHP executable to use. PhpStorm may just suggest the default path 2) For remote web server based debug you do not need to specify any PHP executable at all -- PhpStorm does not care what PHP will be used there as it cannot influence in any way. Even more -- you can debug remote web script (via browser) without specifying any PHP interpreters (which are used fro CLI debug only, not web)

Comment: And how do you explain that it started working right after?

Comment: @zangarmarsh *" then I configured the 20-xdebug.ini in the FPM folder and it's done."*. So .... the key was ... editing **right** config file.